# Making my first webpage, getting stuck at an "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, require

I've done a bunch of research regarding this and keep getting pointed to Browserify, however every Browserify tutorial I watch it ends up not being what I need and i feel like I'd have to explain my project a bit and have someone give me a suggestion from there so here it is:

I have a single script called app.js where I have multiple requires in the beginning:

```
const CSVToJSON = require("csvtojson");
const JSONToCSV = require("json2csv").parse;
const FileSystem = require("fs");
const axios = require('axios')
```

and these consts are used throughout the script.

And here's my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Business Finder Program</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <hr>
      <form>
         <div>
            <label>PASTE YOUR PARAMETERS HERE</label>
            <input type="text" name="params" id='params'>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
            <button onclick="makePostRequest(document.getElementById('params').value)">Send</button>
         </div>
         <br>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I click my submit button it makes a request (not with the given parameters but with the one that is used as a placeholder in my app.js script), and throws the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".

I'm really just looking for somewhere to start, I'm making a tool site for my company so I really just need to get it working, I don't care about anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: well... for one, `fs` isn't going to work in a web browser... so that kinda puts into question the entirety of app.js functioning at all.

Comment: You need to start distinguishing javascript that runs in the browser and javascript that runs on node.js. While both use the same language, they have different functions and modules available. You cannot use `fs` in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

require(...) is a node.js concept. It allows you to load scripts from your hard drive and run them (oversimplified).

The the web and web browsers are not node.js and are much more secure than that. They have no idea how to load from your hard drive, and in fact they don't even know what "require(...)" means.

Applications like browserify and webpack translate node.js applications into web applications for you. But they are built on top of many years of lessons and experience from developers. They are not terribly easy to pick up from a novice point of view.

I think you have 2 options:

1. Learn webpack or browserify for the sake of learning them, but then quit once you have enough code do run your website. (Keep in mind browserify is not the most popular choice anymore)
2. Try to find versions of your scripts that are built for the web, and not for node, e.g. here: https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/issues/153

Answer (score -1):

`require` is essentially something specific to NodeJS. You can't use it in the browser, at least not like that. Browserify and other tools allow you to 'emulate' the NodeJS `require` in a browser.

Have you tried [Parcel](https://parceljs.org)? It's super-easy to use and does all the things you'd expect from it. It might be a better fit for your project than Browserify.

```
$ parcel index.html
```

This will generate a `dist/`-folder containing all the files your webserver needs.

**Edit:** Like the comments point out, you're going to have a bad time using the `fs`-module in a browser. While some modules, such as `events`, can be used in the browser, there's no way to 'emulate' the file system.